# ns2 GPSR wrong the other node

Tags: ns2

(GPSR_KeLiu)When I was doing the NS2 simulation experiment on the GPSR protocol, I always suggested "wrong the other node". I found the problem in the `gpsr_neighbor.cc` file. In the peripheral mode to find the error in the process of the next-hop, according to my analysis, question should be due to the previously defined the next-hop with `ID` -1, no new neighbor in `neighbor_list` so `ID` not updated. So how do I fix this error?